# When I use "Build Variants" as release mode for making final APK file, It can not install

Tags: android

I searched about making the final **APK** file for upload to the **google.play** and I understood that I should change it from debug mode to release mode by using the the **Build Variants** in the android studio.But when I want install the produced **APK** files in my device, It can not install.

Comment: Can provide more details

Comment: Click Build and then generate signed apk and then use release